# expressing-transforming latitude values

Tags: r, data-transformation, terminology, lm

In a dataset, I have this variable `latitude` that contains values such as

`39° 37' 39" N` and `39deg 24min`.

As far as I know, latitude is measured like above internationally.

My question is: To process the above data in order to include them in a linear model for example, which is the proper way to express or format `latitude` values, keeping their scientific and logical aspect?

Comment: The answers to this question could be broad and complex, because issues of coordinate systems, datums, and projections can arise, as well as considerations of how latitude ultimately is related to the other variables of interest. Note, however, that a truly international standard for *representing* latitudes is the "decimal degree" which simply converts your base-60 numbers into base 10. For instance, in base 10, "39° 37' 39" is written "39.6275." For more about this [search the GIS site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=decimal+degree).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a function to transform `latitude` into a decimal. As @whuber suggests in his comment, despite the theoretical complexity of representing latitudes, the simplest way to achieve that is illustrated below.

Suppose we have a value of `39° 37' 39" N` for `lat` variable. Another expression of that value would be:

`lat = a + b/60 + c/3600`, where `a = 39` degrees, `b = 37` minutes and `c = 39` seconds.

Calculating that results to `lat = 39.6275` with a general "direction" to the north (`N`).

Now this is the most common case. In the case where instead of `N` we have `E` for *East* nothing changes, and for cases where we have `S`, or `W` for *South* and *West* accordingly the result would be:

`lat = lat * -1`.

This way latitude can be included in a linear regression model. It is supposed to have a linear correlation with `temperature` for example (as seen in R using  `lm(temperature~latitude)`).

There are several places to look for more information. Some I found useful are  [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140189/converting-latitude-and-longitude-to-decimal-values), [[2]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=decimal%20degree), [[3]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion)

Comment: It's good practice to answer your own question if you have an answer as good or better than anyone else's, which here is true. However, the idea of a "linear correlation" between temperature and latitude, whatever that means precisely is at best only a local approximation. Globally, even at the very crudest level the tropics being warmer than the poles means that the relation is not even monotonic.

Comment: practically, ploting an `lm(temp~lat)` would produce something linear. What is a monotonic relation btw?

Comment: Consider any decent atlas with climate maps. On monotonic see e.g. any mathematical dictionary or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function